# Is canvas.getContext('2d') sync or async?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Is canvas.getContext('2d') sync or async. I am confused with this and cannot find a clear answer.
Do i need to wait till I get the context using some sort of async or await mechanism in javascript even after canvas has rendered on the dom?

Comment: Did you try it? It literally would have taken you less time than posting this question.

Comment: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext), and every example on the web. No, you don't have to wait for anything. If you're having some problem using the result, it probably would have helped the question a **lot** if you'd shown the problem you were having.

Comment: So, i tried that out, just posted the question here, because a senior developer has used async and await with it in the code. So i want to be totally sure before raising this with him.

Comment: Are you sure they were awaiting for this method and not say a network request or an image to load in the same function?

Answer (score 3):

It is sync, you do not need to wait.

Answer (score 1):

It is a synchronous function however your usage is incorrect. You should equate that to a variable.

Like this:

```
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
```

Then you can do things like:

```
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
```